# How to update user's hireDate attribute in Azure AD using Graph REST API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I searched for similar questions but did not find answer I was looking for.

My goal is to update all users in AAD with hireDate.

At first I tried to do so using client credentials flow.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/espiradev.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type:client_credentials
client_id:{{client_id}}
client_secret:{{client_secret}}
resource:https://graph.microsoft.com
```

After I got access code I called:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[user1]
Authorization:bearer {{access_token}}
Content-Type:application/json
{
 "hireDate": "2019-05-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```

Response:

```
"error": {
  "code": "-1, Microsoft.Office.Server.Directory.DirectoryObjectUnauthorizedAccessException",
  "message": "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.",
  "innerError": {}
}
```

Second try was using password flow (client and user credentials). I used my global admin [user1] credentials and called same HTTP request. Response was  `HTTP 204` (everything OK).

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/espiradev.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type:password
client_id:{{client_id}}
client_secret:{{client_secret}}
resource:https://graph.microsoft.com
username:{{user1_upn}}
password:{{user1_password}}
```

Unfortunately, when I tried to update other [user2] it went like this:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[user2]
Authorization:bearer {{access_token}}
Content-Type:application/json
{
  "hireDate": "2019-05-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```

Response:

```
"error": {
   "code": "-1, Microsoft.Office.Server.Directory.DirectoryObjectUnauthorizedAccessException",
   "message": "Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.",
   "innerError": {}
}
```

If I am using [user2] credentials to get access token then I can update [user2] hireDate, but can not update [user1].

Application permissions:
[Application permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnb3c.png)

**UPDATED:**
Decoded access token has these permissions:

```
"scp": "Directory.AccessAsUser.All Directory.ReadWrite.All User.ManageIdentities.All User.ReadWrite User.ReadWrite.All"
```

**UPDATED[2]:**
both [user1] and [user2] has Office 365 E1 licences assigned (including SharePoint Online (Plan 1))

Am I doing something wrong? If anyone has a solution to share, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check whether the access token has all those scopes? Can you share the decoded token content?

Comment: Yes I checked decoded access token and all mentioned permissions was there. adding this info to post.

Comment: Does your tenant have a SPO license?

Comment: Both [user1] and [user2] has Office 365 E1 licence assigned (including SharePoint Online (Plan 1)). Is that is what you asked for or I am missing something?

Comment: That's it. Thanks, I'm already taking a look at this and will let you know ASAP.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark the answer by clicking the arrow and verify by clicking the emoji below. Doing so helps others find answers to their related questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the office licenses, the global admin user should have Sites.ReadWrite.All scope permission in the token to update the "hireDate" property for other users.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was missing.

Comment: No response from MS on how to resolve this issue (it is reported everywhere).  This was the fix that worked!  Amazing response.  Thank you!